# scheme without global sections

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $R$ be an arbitrary non zero ring and $X$ a $R$-scheme. Is it possible that the ring of global sections $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ might be a zero ring? The cruical point is that despite of the $R$-scheme structure for $X$ providing the existence of ring map $R \to H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ I see no obstruction for this map to be a zero map.

Comment: I guess this is not really what you are looking for, but the spectrum of the zero ring is a $R$-scheme for any $R$. You might want a non-empty scheme though.

Comment: What about constant maps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The empty scheme has zero global sections, because for any scheme $X$,  $\mathcal{O}_X(\emptyset)$ is the zero ring.

Conversely, any scheme with zero global sections is empty.

*Proof:* Suppose $X$ has zero global sections. Let $U\subseteq X$ be an affine open set, isomorphic to $\text{Spec}(A)$. Then there is a restriction map $\rho^X_U\colon \mathcal{O}_X(X)\to \mathcal{O}_X(U)$, so $A = \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is the zero ring (because $1_A = \rho^X_U(1) = \rho^X_U(0) = 0_A$). Since the zero ring has no prime ideals, $U$ is empty. Now $X$ admits a cover by affine open sets, all of which must be empty, so $X$ is empty.

Comment: could you explain why a scheme with zero global sections must be empty? wlog it's a $R:= \mathbb{Z}$-scheme so we have a map $R \to H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X) $. Assume $X$ is non empty scheme: why this ring map cannot be a zero map?

Comment: @TimGrosskreutz I've updated my answer with more details.

Comment: Another way to see this is that you always have a map, for any locally ringed space $X$, $X\to\mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_X(X))$. If $\mathcal{O}_X(X)=0$ then you have a map $X\to \varnothing$, which means that you're nothing (both metaphorically, and literally).